# Is there any way to align the table contents in the same line in the teams bot framework?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

The below image shows how the current table is displayed on teams. We can see that the cells are not aligned properly. Using adaptive card (columnset).

[The image shows how the cells are not aligned and the separator is jagged.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H02Eo.png)

Below is the json payload.

```
{
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.0",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "ColumnSet",
        "columns": [
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "weight": "bolder",
                        "text": "LMAOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "separator":true,
                        "text": "Apple"
                    },{
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "separator":true,
                        "text": "Kiwi"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "weight": "bolder",
                        "text": "YEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "separator":true,
                        "text": "Fruit"
                    },{
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "separator":true,
                        "text": "Fruit"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "weight": "bolder",
                        "text": "Price"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "separator":true,
                        "text": "2"
                    },{
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "separator":true,
                        "text": "1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Is there a way to keep all the rows in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it from my end & it's working fine for me:

[image]

I tried to decrease the browser size and still it's working fine:
[image]

**I tested it in both Teams Desktop client and browser client and it's working fine for me**

Comment: I tried this method but as you can see the entire text is not shown. When we use warp: true the columns become jagged

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try using below JSON file:

```
 {
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.0",
"body": [
{
    "type": "ColumnSet",
    "columns": [
        {
            "type": "Column",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "weight": "bolder",
                    "text": "LMAOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO",
                    "wrap": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Column",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "weight": "bolder",
                    "text": "YEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE",
                    "wrap": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Column",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "weight": "bolder",
                    "text": "Price",
                    "wrap": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "type": "ColumnSet",
    "columns": [
        {
            "type": "Column",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "separator":true,
                    "text": "Apple"
                },{
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "separator":true,
                    "text": "Kiwi"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Column",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "separator":true,
                    "text": "Fruit"
                },{
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "separator":true,
                    "text": "Fruit"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Column",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "separator":true,
                    "text": "2"
                },{
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "separator":true,
                    "text": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
  ]
 }
```